# Creating correct proportions for Minecraft projects

Tags: modeling, animation

I apologize if the question isn't very specific; I can't think of any other way to word it.
I'm looking to make Minecraft animations with Blender. One of the big obstacles I've run into is the proportions.
Say, how can I make a Minecraft character the right size to fit with the Minecraft build I have in an obj? This doubles for other entities, such as a creeper, a pig, etc.
I've looked up tutorials on "How to make a Minecraft animation with Blender," but they all (by "They all," I mean all the ones I've seen) tell you to download a starter .obj, which I really don't want to do.
I love being able to create anything and everything in Blender from scratch, but if I use a starter .obj, that ability isn't there at the point I'd like it to be at.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you considered downloading the starter .obj anyway and loading it and making notes about the dimensions? Once you know those you can discard the starter obj. and fix your own.

Comment: I haven't, but that's a very good idea... Thank you! I'll give it a try.

Comment: I gave an answer here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82249/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-convert-2d-images-to-single-3d-model   that covers how to relate blueprints to ¾ view with specific rules. I invite you to take a look, hopefully you find it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is more of a 2D/drawing question so I'll keep my answer very light.

It’s all in the references. You need to find a front view and a side view that are as close to actual size as possible. In other words they have to look similar to blueprints. Then you just need to measure, like with Gimp, and see the ratios. If the vertical is 10 and the horizontal 7 from the front view and 10 and, say, 5 in depth from the side, then you obviously have a 7 to 5 ratio from top view. As a note, if the objects are at different relative sizes, you can scale one of the images until the verticals coincide. It can be done by numbers too, but I don’t think is necessary to explain.

So ideally is to make the images yourself and get the desired angles. Proportions can be extracted from a  ¾ quarter view too, but, again, I don’t think this is a Blender topic, rather a drawing one.